# Keep comments but turn off commenting

Tags: css, comments

What I mean is this: I have over 600 comments in my site, and I want to keep them all, but, I want to remove the ability to comment.

If I turn off comments then everything is removed.

I can achieve this by hiding the comment form using CSS "hide" but I feel that that isn't the best approach.

Is there "another way"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is theme specific. The default themes don't do this, and instead simply state that comments are closed:

[image]

If comments are turned off, they change the comment form. But your theme appears to change the entire comment section instead of just the form.

You're going to have to either modify your theme or ask your theme vendor to fix this. Take a look at `comments.php`, it's probably in there, but it may be implemented differently in your theme. To find out how you will need to look at the PHP code. Take a look at how twentytwenty and twentynineteen do it for what it should look like.

Also, make sure you use a child theme to make the modification  or it'll be undone when you update the theme